# Obtaining the sub-array from the main array where each sub-array is shifted to right by one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a huge numpy array a=[55,12,12....] .Now I want to take sub-array of size 300 beginning[from 55] from the array a, and move one position to right[from 12] and take the new sub array.I want to keep doing this until I get the last 300 elements. Using 'for loops' is taking forever because I have many arrays that I have to do the above operation

How would I speed up this process? 
This is the original appraoch

```
i=0
WINDOW=300
while (i+WINDOW)<len(a):
  new_a = np.append(new_a,np.array([a[i:i+WINDOW+1]]),axis=0)
  i=i+1
```

This is second approach I tried which decreased the computational time by almost half

```
i=0
WINDOW=300
mid=int(len(a)/2)
while (i+WINDOW)<int(len(a)/2):
  part1 = np.append(part1,np.array([a[i:i+WINDOW+1]]),axis=0)
  part2 = np.append(part2,np.array([a[mid+i:mid+i+WINDOW+1]]),axis=0)
  i=i+1
```

Comment: Show us your loop based try?

Comment: Speed up what process? The answer depends on what you want to do with your sub arrays.

Comment: Code and second approach added  @Divakar

Comment: @ Paul Panzer I want to speed up the process of creating these sub-arrays, these sub-arrays are appended to one numpy array, which is then used to write into a csv file.

Comment: why do you need to append everything together? slice the original array and write that slice into .csv file without moving it around in memory.

Comment: Because I have many files which from I get many arrays on which the sub array operation has to be performed. So after I do the sub-array operation on all the arrays of a single file, I write into csv. @lenik

Answer (score 1):

Numpy will reallocate space upon each call of `np.append`, because the size of the array you want to write to increases upon each iteration. You could allocate the array in advance, since you know its size is `len(a)-WINDOW+1` by `WINDOW`, and index explicitly.

```py
new_a = np.zeros([len(a)-WINDOW+1, WINDOW])
for i in range(len(a)-WINDOW+1):
    new_a[i] = a[i:i+WINDOW]
```